# A problem with lavalink discord example cog

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm using the example cog of discord.py lavalink, and I'm having an error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'"

I've already installed lavalink, and not sure what is causing this.

I've check around for other posts who may have similar issues and couldn't find any.

https://github.com/Devoxin/Lavalink.py/blob/master/examples/music.py
The code that I'm using.

Comment: Would you post the traceback?? Traceback is everything in error handling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you try this video as it gives a better example that works:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X1DEos_9dJo.

I usually get the 'Nonetype' error when someone tries to play something but the command still works perfectly fine. I usually ignore this error because all of the music commands I use on my bot work perfectly fine with it.

The video also has a github repo so you can test to see if it works.